# Swift. How to use a different base class for DEBUG mode?

Tags: swift, preprocessor

I am trying to do this. But it's producing compile errors:

```
#if DEBUG
class BaseRule<T> : NSObject, RuleProtocol
#else
class BaseRule<T> : RuleProtocol
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
#if DEBUG
typealias RuleBase = NSObject
#else
typealias RuleBase = AnyObject
#endif

class BaseRule<T> : RuleBase, RuleProtocol {
```